# Can't install mysql on python

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to coding and currently working with python on geospatial development for a project. One of the modules I need is MySQL but whenever I try to install it using pip I get an error.

install code:

```
$ pip3 install mysql

ERROR: Cannot install mysql==0.0.1, mysql==0.0.2 and mysql==0.0.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    mysql 0.0.3 depends on mysqlclient
    mysql 0.0.2 depends on mysqlclient
    mysql 0.0.1 depends on MySQL-python

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Comment: The MySQLdb package is provided by the `mysqlclient` PyPI package: `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: Also, the [`mysql` package description](https://pypi.org/project/mysql/) specifically says _"This package is a ‘virtual package’, which requires MySQL-python (Python 2) or mysqlclient (Python 3) to install. In effect, this means ‘pip install mysql’ will actually install MySQL-python. **Instead of depending on this package, please depend on the relevant package directly.**"_

Comment: thank you this worked